# Show downloaded html inside of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

Im trying to create kind of a user interface with a downloaded html-string and an iframe. What my 'Submitta' ActionResult does is returning a html-page as a JSON string. And then I try to append it to an iframe so I can record and save clicks. See code below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Submitta/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(paket),
        success: function (data) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
            var html = data.Url;
            iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
            renderat = true;

            $('#frame').on('load', function () {
                console.log("load");
                var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow;

                $(iframeDoc).mouseover(function (event) {


                }).click(function (event) {
                    console.log($(event.target.valueOf()));
                });
            });

        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    })
```

Which I am having problem with rendering due to a browser error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:xxxx" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

Am I going at this project the wrong way? Is it not possible to work with iframes in this way?
For the record does this JQuery click function work when the iframe is directly rendered from a local .html file. But not when it has html appended to it.

Comment: Does your "Submitta" return an Url or a HTML page?

Comment: It returns a html page

Comment: iframe's `src` should be a valid URL like `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>` or some relative URL `extraContent.do`. Just change it like this `iframe.src=html`. You're firing an Ajax call just to get the URL and then set to iframe src which will fire another call. Can't you fire an Ajax call to get the second URL directly, get the HTML and update in a div or something ?

Comment: @Arkantos I think the point is he's not getting an URL back from his Ajax, like `"http://www.google.com"`. He is getting something like `<html><body></body></html>`

Comment: Could you print on your console what you are getting in your `data` object? Just put in the beginning of success callback like this `success: function (data) { console.log(data) ...`

Comment: Oops, my mistake :) I thought he's getting URL in JSON response.

Comment: @user3581054.. what is the html string you're getting in `/Home/Submitta/` ? Can you post some sample html in your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of an iFrame like a window into another tab on your browser... opening a page within a page. What you're doing, is trying to transmit the data via json, generate the page on the client-side, and then put that page in the iframe... if that's the case, then you could just eliminate the iframte all together and put your generated HTML into a div or something using jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Submitta/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(paket),
    success: function (data) {
        // take "data" and do what you gotta do to
        // get it into HTML...
        var resulthtml = "";

        // put that HTML generated above into 
        // your results div like this:
        $("#resultsdiv").html(resulthtml);

    },
    error: function (err) {
        $("#resultsdiv").html("Something went wrong.");
    }
});
```